# MKPinAnnotationView no longer using images in ios9

Tags: mapkit

Since the iOS9 upgrade, the custom images on my MKPinAnnotationView are no longer showing up.  Is there a documented change somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per someone from Apple on the developer forums:

> MKPinAnnotationView manages its own pin image. If you'd like to set a
>   custom image, it's best to use MKAnnotationView directly.

From: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3920

I was doing this as well, and a simple switch to use `MKAnnotationView` worked for me. My guess is this was never supposed to work. I couldn't find any documentation on an `image` property for `MKPinAnnotationView`